# How to concatenate list of integers into a single number

Tags: list-manipulation

Is there a way to concatenate the elements of a list into **ONE** number?

For example, if there is a list `L={13,5,8,0}`, then I am looking for a way to append `13`, `5`, `8` and `0` to produce the result `13580`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can convert the list numbers to strings, then join and finally convert back to number:

```
L = {13, 5, 8, 0};

ToExpression[StringJoin[ToString /@ L]]
(* 13580 *)
```

Answer (score 10):

Or FromDigits:

```
FromDigits[{13, 5, 8, 0}]

13580
```

Comment: (+1) you will need something like `FromDigits[Flatten@IntegerDigits@L]` to cover cases like `L={1, 13, 5, 8, 0}`.

Comment: @kglr 's comment, and answer, show the proper way to use IntegerDigits.  Please see those.

Answer (score 10):

```
FromDigits @ StringJoin @ IntegerString @ L
```

> 13580

```
FromDigits @ StringJoin @ IntegerString @ {13, 5, 38, 13}
```

> 1353813